# как убрать сss свойства bootstrapa?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

у меня есть карточка и в ней есть кнопка.Выглядит это вот так :
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

я хочу сделать так чтобы при нажатие кнопки,она не оставалась черной.
Сделал с помощью:

```
.btn:active {
    background-color: white;
}
```

но хочу сделать так чтобы вообще никакого свойста не было.Если оставить боле с задним фоном пустым,автоматом применяется цвет заднего фона бутсрапа.А я хочу сделать так чтобы не моего значения там не было и не значение бутстрапа.Как это сделать?

Comment: Такое можно сделать через JavaScript

Comment: @SergeyGlazirin можно через css или html?

Comment: Удалить класс вряд ли получится через css. Можно добавить код карточки, чтобы было понятнее что нужно поправить, и добавить пример поведения до и после, чтобы было понятно что делать